# Save Glimpse data as report

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, performance-testing, glimpse

I am looking to capture web application performance (total time taken) to visualize a code change impact. I am not looking at scientific precision method as of now (we may employ an automated tool at later stage) just a quick comparison will do.

My web application is ASP.NET MVC4 application. I am using Glimpse 1.8.2 and can see the request timing in Glimpse on browser. For a quick comparison, my plan is to capture timings first for few known request (i.e. SearchController.AddNewSearch()), deploy the change and then again monitor the time for comparison.

I was wondering if there is an option I can export the data Glimpse capture into xls or csv format.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar question has been answered in the Glimpse discussion group [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/getglimpse-dev/fup_gzQ8Hbs).

There are a couple of options as mentioned in the thread above, the simplest solution provided there is to call `window.glimpse.data.currentData();` in the JavaScript console to get the data used for the current requested page and then stringify it and write it to a file.

Comment: I wonder if there is an event that would fire when `window.glimpse.data.currentData` becomes available? It would appear one would have to `glimpse.pubsub.subscribe('trigger.data.init', handler)`, but I'm not sure how to reliably call that given that glimpse injects its script into the page via a HTTP handler, so you can't make sure your script is later on the page, so that `window.glimpse` is available when you try to access it.